# javascript get datepicker start or end value of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker'">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

I know the method goes something like this:

```
datestart = $("#datepicker").find("input").val();
```

However this returns 2 different value (Only showing the first one regardless what I do), how do I go about getting just the start or the end of the value?

I was trying something like this:

```
datestart = $("#datepicker2").find("input").attributes['name'=start].val();
```

Obviously that doesn't work... Can anyone shine some light on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right:

```
datestart = $("#datepicker").find("input[name='start']").val();
dateend = $("#datepicker").find("input[name='end']").val();
```

or better yet:

```
datestart = $("#datepicker input[name='start']").val();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! I'll accept the answer when it allows me to XD

Answer (score 0):

you can write the following to get the first value

```
$("input[name=start]").val();
```

to get the second value use

```
$("input[name=end]").val();
```